# Where do I start optimizing the JVM?

Tags: java, optimization

I'm kinda confused as to where to start looking to optimize my java-based application. Can someone give me some guidance as to what to look for?

Add note:

The java application I'm running is open source but I don't want to tweak it myself as I'm not capable of doing it. So what I'm looking at is on how to optimize the execution environment so as to fit the current behavior of the app. By the way, the application is hudson, a java-based continuous integration system.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean with optimize? Make your code running faster?

Comment: *@icasimpan*: Note that your title asks for something different than your question body. Your question title has it wrong. The JVM is only the thing that executes your program; so if you're not happy with your program's performance, you should first look at the program *itself*, instead of at its execution environment. (That said, it would quite likely be fairly difficult manipulating the JVM, anyway.)

Comment: @stakx: I've modified the question to explain why I want the JVM optimized instead of the app. Thanks for the FYI ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before start optimizing try to find out where you do you have a problem. Is your application CPU bound, memory-bound, or I/O bound? When you know this, try to find the biggest performance impact first and try to optimize it. Use Java profilers to find the problems in your application or configuration.

A good starting point for the whole process could be the [Java Performance Tuning](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/) site.

Answer (score 3):

Official [Java Performance Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/performance-138178.html) and [Java SE Performance at a Glance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/performance-jsp-141338.html)

Answer (score 0):

- Read Java HotSpot VM options [performance tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#PerformanceTuning).
- Try unlock experimental VM options(-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC 
  -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods).
- Optimizes the code.

Answer (score 0):

Before you attempt to optimise the JVM, I suggest you optimise your code.  You can use a profiler like VisualVM (free) or YourKit (commercial) to look at CPU and memory performance bottleneck.  Often simple changes can make a big difference.

Conversely, you can change lots of JVM options and not be sure its really helped.